# Is it possible to connect Amazon FreeRTOS Windows Simulator to local machine broker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, freertos

It is easy to send data from amazon FreeRTOS windows simulator to aws MQTT broker.
But I want to send data from amazon FreeRTOS windows simulator to local machine broker.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.freertos.org/mqtt/preconfiguredexamples.html) is a demo sending to mosquitto MQTT broker running on a local machine, and [here](https://www.freertos.org/mqtt/preconfiguredexamplesTLS.html) is a demo connecting to test.mosquitto.org in the cloud.  Both are a work in progress.

Comment: I am asking about "AWS FreeRTOS" not "FreeRTOS".
I am getting network connecting error every time when I try to connect with local mqtt broker from AWS FreeRTOS windows simulator.